# delphi Undeclared identifier: 'scanline'

Tags: delphi, identifier, scanline

i have the following error message in Delphi 7:

**Undeclared identifier: 'scanline'**

my uses:
uses
  Windows, Messages, SysUtils, Variants, Classes, Graphics, Controls, Forms,
  Dialogs, Menus, Buttons, StdCtrls, ExtCtrls,math, ComCtrls;

my part of code:

```
screenshot(0,0,screen.Width,screen.Height,bmp);
for a:=1 to screen.Height do begin
pxl:=scanline[a-1];
end;
```

where pxl is `PByteArray`;

`screenshot` is a procedure that catching the selected area into a bitmap...

AFAIK scanline function using Graphics library, but it does not works..

What I am doing wrong?

Thanks

Comment: `ScanLine` is a method of `TBitmap`, not a stand-alone function. See the documentation for [TBitmap,ScanLine.](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Seattle/en/Vcl.Graphics.TBitmap.ScanLine) - the link is for Delphi 10 Seattle, but it's still relevant to Delphi 7. What exactly do you expect `scanline[a-1]` to be accessing? Psychic pixels?

Comment: i need to "see" what is in the desktop and when i find the wanted color combination of pixels, it will fire a procedure

Comment: As I said, `ScanLine` is a method of `TBitmap`. I've shown you the documentation. Your use is a simple lack of reading of the documentation; you can't use `ScanLine` by itself, because it doesn't exist by itself. Your code accesses `scanline` of nothing, meaning there is nothing to retrieve a scanline from except imaginary pixels. I presume that the `bmp` you're passing to `screenshot` is a `TBitmap`, so use it: `bmp.ScanLine`.

Comment: yeah sorry, bmp.scanline worked fine...   I need to take a rest :)   Thanks, it solved my problem...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`[ScanLine][1]` is not a standalone function. It's a method of some graphics classes such as TBitmap. You need an instance of one of those classes in order to call ScanLine. ScanLine also does not return a single pixel, but an entire line of pixels at once.

Presuming that the `bmp` in your call to `screenshot` is a `TBitmap`, you can  use `bmp.ScanLine[a - 1];`, which would return a pointer to an entire line (row) of pixels.